# CodeIgniter updating database MULTIDIMENSIONAL data row with checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, codeigniter

Im confused. I have been analyzing this for hours..
What I want:
"EACH table row with the checkbox thats checked would be updated with the value inputted."

Anyone can help?
thank you,

Leo

Admin.php

```
function submit_acc(){
        $this->access_chk(); //CHECK USER ACCESS
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters(' ', '<br />');
         $checkbox=$this->input->post('cek');
        $sbm=$this->input->post('sbm');
        if($sbm == "Update" && $checkbox!=false){
            foreach ($checkbox as $row_id) {
             // echo($this->input->post('bank_accname'));
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("type", "bank name", "required");
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("isactive", "Status Bank", "required");

            if(!$this->form_validation->run()){ exit(validation_errors()); }
echo "update x where y =$row_id";
echo $_POST["accgroup"].$_POST["type"].$this->input->post('bank_accname').$_POST["bank_accnumber"].$_POST["isactive"];

$data[] = array (
        "acc_id"                =>  $row_id,
        "acc_accgroup_id"       =>  $_POST["accgroup"],
        "acc_bank_name"         =>  $_POST["type"],
        "acc_bank_accname"      =>  $this->input->post('bank_accname'),
        "acc_bank_accnumber"    =>  $_POST["bank_accnumber"],
        "acc_isactive"          =>  $_POST["isactive"]
    );
              $uid=$row_id;
            //      echo $uid;
            }

            //var_dump($data);
            //var_dump($checkbox);
$this->db->update_batch('acc', $data, 'acc_id');
exit("end");
```

View.php

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url("admin/submit_acc"); ?>" method="post" id="form">
<table>
        <tr >
            <td align="center"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php if(isset($r)) echo $r["acc_id"]; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="isactive[]" value="<?php if(isset($r)) echo $r["acc_isactive"]; ?>" />
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" style="width:200px;" value="<?php if(isset($r)) echo $r["acc_bank_name"]; ?>" name="type[]"  id="type" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" style="width:200px;" value="<?php if(isset($r)) echo $r["acc_bank_accname"]; ?>" name="bank_accname[]" id="bank_accname"  /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="textbox" style="width:200px;" value="<?php if(isset($r)) echo $r["acc_bank_accnumber"]; ?>" name="bank_accnumber[]"  id="bank_accnumber" /></td>


<!--<input type='radio' name="isactive_<?php echo $r['acc_id'];?>" value=1 
            <?php if ($r["acc_isactive"]=='1') echo 'checked'; ?>  > -->

&nbsp;G&nbsp;       
        <select name="accgroup[]">
        <option value='<?php echo $r["accgroup_no"]; ?>' id="account_id"><?php echo $r['accgroup_no']; ?></option>
        <?php echo $stropt; ?></select>
<!-- <input type='radio' name='isactive_<?php echo $r['acc_id'];?>' value=0 <?php if ($r["acc_isactive"]=='0')echo 'checked'; ?>> Off&nbsp; -->
```

" >

```
            </table>
   </form>
```

MY TRY AND ITS NOT WORKING : if I dont select the first row, the second row wont be updated . the point is my checkbox should be checked all to function properly. if not, it would start updating the rows according to numbers of checked checkboxes. Can somebody please tell me what did I miss?????

```
    $data=array();          

    $data['checkbox']=$this->input->post('cek');
    $data['id']=$this->input->post('id',true);
    $data['accgroup']=$this->input->post('accgroup',true);
    $data['type']=$this->input->post('type',true);
    $data['bank_accname']=$this->input->post('bank_accname',true);
    $data['bank_accnumber']=$this->input->post('bank_accnumber',true);
    $data['isactive']=$this->input->post('isactive',true);

        $sbm=$this->input->post('sbm');

        if($sbm == "Update" && $data['checkbox']!=false){



    foreach ($data['checkbox'] as $key => $each) {

             // echo($this->input->post('bank_accname'));
             echo $data["accgroup"][$key];
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("type", "bank name", "required");
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("isactive", "Status Bank", "required");

            if(!$this->form_validation->run()){ exit(validation_errors()); }

              $temp[] = array (
        "acc_id"                =>  $data["id"][$key]   ,
        "acc_accgroup_id"       =>  $data["accgroup"][$key],
        "acc_bank_name"         =>  $data["type"][$key],
        "acc_bank_accname"      =>  $data['bank_accname'][$key],
        "acc_bank_accnumber"    =>  $data["bank_accnumber"][$key],
        "acc_isactive"          =>  $data["isactive"][$key]
    );
              $uid=$key;
            //      echo $uid;
            }

            var_dump($temp);
            //var_dump($checkbox);
$this->db->update_batch('acc', $temp, 'acc_id');
exit("end");
```

Comment: First, if you want multiple values to be chekced, you have to use checkbox instead of radio.

Comment: so its not possible to use radio button? I was converting from a pure PHP into PHP with codeigniter framework. the old interface is using these radio buttons. @Dimitris

Comment: thank you for commenting can u help me tell me what I missed in the looping of array's array values? I havent had a grip of this multidimensional array loop. @DimitrisKontoulis

Comment: when I check all the checkboxes, it updated all the rows. but when I selected the second only. it still updated the first row but not the second.

Comment: Since you are saving the values while yo uare in a foreach loop, and you have single key, valu pairs, why yare you using batch_update? Try to run a normal update.

Comment: Thank you Dimitris. I have used an individual update instead of batch update. thank you. :)

Comment: Is it working as intended?

Comment: Yeah, it is working as intended. @DimitrisKontoulis thank you. I just post another question about ci. Could u please check it out? :(